# Creating savepoints and starting from a specific node in apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

#### Creating savepoints

Currently savepoints are created by saving the pipeline to a csv file after each transformation. 
The setup in general looks like this:

[image: savepoint pipeline]

I am doing this by having a wrapper transform object to which I can provide a transformation function and an optional savepoint parameter. 
The transform object can create savepoints, if they are provided:

```
class SavePointNode(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, transform, savepoint=None, **kwargs):
        super(beam.PTransform, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.transform = transform
        self.savepoint = savepoint

    def expand(self, p):

        # transform data
        result = p | beam.ParDo(self.transform)

        # load to savepoint if available
        if self.savepoint:
            return result | beam.io.WriteToText(self.savepoint)

        return result
```

My first question is the following:

- Is there already a default way to create savepoints in Apache Beam?

#### Loading savepoints

By creating savepoints I want to be able to restart the pipeline at a specific node to save time by not retracing each step up to a savepoint.
For example: If an error occured in the third transform step:

[image: error in third transform step]

I want to be able to restart the pipeline from the savepoint created by the second transform step:

[image: restart at second savepoint]

My questions regarding this are the following:

- Is there currently a default way to do this in Apache Beam?
- If not are there any other good ways to achieve this behaviour?
- Have I been going about this the wrong way and could there be any other solutions to reduce the reloading time if an error occurred provided by Apache Beam?